# Correct description of a laser beam

Tags: electromagnetism, laser

For the description of the electromagnetic field using a [gaussian beam](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam) one finds a time-**in**dependent intensity (irradiance).

I guess this is an artefact of the complex ansatz for the electromagnetic field. The correct description would be to use the real part only, which results in a time-dependent intensity similar to a propagating wave.

Am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you are trying to express.  An expression for irradiance can be calculated, but it is derived from the expression of the electric field.   The time dependent expression arises from the taking of the time dependence as $\exp{i\omega t}$ (or $\sin{\omega t}$ but the math would be more difficult using sines).

Comment: Using the complex expression means that the time dependence of the irradiance cancels; in my opinion this is wrong, the irradiance is time dependent.

Comment: To my knowledge, irradiance is calculated by averaging over a time period longer than a period, and is not time dependent.  I will be happy to be corrected if you can point me to a definition that says otherwise

Comment: It’s not always mentioned explicitly, but yes, this is the source of my confusion. So the Poynting vector is time-dependent, whereas irradiance isn‘t. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Poynting vector, $S=E \times H$, has two factors of time-dependent field. Thus, it has both time-dependent and time-independent terms. The time-dependent term oscillates at the second harmonic frequency. So, yes, if one were able to measure power flow at frequency $2\omega$, then one would find that the power flow is indeed time-dependent. This is possible for microwaves, for example (not so much for visible light). Of course, quantities such as irradiance are usually defined explicitly in terms of the time-independent component.